# Paired power supply control

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, transistors

I am designing an op amp bipolar supply, +-5v. In this situation, I want some type of equal positive/negative voltage power up, but controlled by the negative rail, so that in the event that the negative rail doesn’t power up, that the positive rail doesn’t either.

Ive considered using an op amp in inverting configuration, or something like this schematic, although ideally this would track rather than just switch at the npn vf. Is there some other type of circuit I am overlooking? [image]

Googling either voltage mirror or voltage inverter yields tons of stuff unrelated to the problem, like current mirror stuff etc..

Comment: It may help the answers if you explain what problem you're trying to solve. Why is it OK for the +5 V to fail but not the -5 V?

Comment: In this situation <=0 volts out is a fail safe condition, where upper level systems keep bad things from happening. A 50mv(or whatever the output swing is) out on the op amp because of a failed negative power rail could cause issues.

Comment: At OUT you will get slightly less than 5 V due to the saturation voltage of the PNP, I'd use a PMOS to solve that. also you need a resistor between the Base - Emitter of the PNP (or PMOS) so that it will switch off properly. And the NPN is the wrong way round (swap Base and Emitter).